# How to Style up the RadioList in yii2?

Tags: css, yii2

I'm trying to style up the Radiolist like - `jsfiddle.net/fqJg7`
The code of radiobuttons in my case is -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'wp_jhareq')->radioList(['Yes'=>'Yes','No'=>'No']); ?>
```

And by this piece of code, the html comes as below -

[image]

i can see that the `<label for = "Yes">Yes</label>` is not present in my case.

The css i'm trying -

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}

label[value="Yes"],label[value="No"]{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background: url("/my/path/images/tick.png") left center no-repeat;
    //background-position: 0 30px;
    line-height: 24px
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

Present Output:

[image]

How to achieve this one.

Comment: you never added the source html the one you are following are want to make like one? also you should avoid adding images for the code. they are least helpfull adding code as text allow others to copy and run/fix it quickly and you might get more better replies to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize Yii way of outputting your fields, set the [$template](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield) property on your field.

In your specific case, you could just change your CSS selectors from `label[value="Yes"],label[value="No"]` to `.radio label`.